# R seems Weird, Python seems goes well in the same way

Tags: python, r, function, loops, for-loop

The following codes run the result of unexpected, i think that is somewhat weird, firstly define the featfun():

```
featfun <- function(yi_1, yi, i) {
    all_fea <- list(c(1, 2, 2),
                    c(1, 2, 3),
                    c(1, 1, 2),
                    c(2, 1, 3),
                    c(2, 1, 2),
                    c(2, 2, 3),
                    c(   1, 1),
                    c(   2, 1),
                    c(   2, 2),
                    c(   1, 2),
                    c(   1, 3),
                    c(   2, 3))
    weights <- c(1,1,0.6,1,1,0.2,1,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.5)

    idx1 <- 0; idx2 <- 0
    if (list(c(yi_1, yi, i)) %in% all_fea) {
      idx1 <- which(all_fea %in% list(c(yi_1, yi, i)))
    }
    if (list(c(yi, i)) %in% all_fea) {
      idx2 <- which(all_fea %in% list(c(yi, i)))
    }

    if (idx1 != 0 & idx2 != 0) {
      return(list(c(1, weights[idx1]), c(1, weights[idx2])))
    } else if (idx1 != 0 & idx2 == 0) {
      return(list(c(1, weights[idx1])))
    } else if (idx1 == 0 & idx2 != 0) {
      return(list(c(1, weights[idx2])))
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  }

 > featfun(1,1,2)
    [[1]]
    [1] 1.0 0.6

    [[2]]
    [1] 1.0 0.8
```

I combine the featfun() with for loops：

```
> for (k in seq(2,3)) {
  +   cat("k=",k,"\n")
  +   for (i in seq(1, 2)) {
    +     cat("i=", i,"\n")
    +     print(featfun(1, i, k))
    +   }
  + }
k= 2 
i= 1 
[[1]]
[1] 1.0 0.6

i= 2 
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.0 0.5

k= 3 
i= 1 
[[1]]
[1] 1.0 0.8

i= 2 
[[1]]
[1] 1 1
```

As we can see, when k = 2,i = 1, it only return the first element “[1] 1.0 0.6” , and the second element is missing, it is not the same as the result of featfun(1,1,2).

Further, I rewrite the codes by using python. Following is the python codes:

```
def featfun(yi_1, yi, i):
  all_fea = [
    [1,2,2],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,1,2],
    [2,1,3],
    [2,1,2],
    [2,2,3],
    [  1,1],
    [  2,1],
    [  2,2],
    [  1,2],
    [  1,3],
    [  2,3]]
  weights = [1,1,0.6,1,1,0.2,1,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.5]
  idx1 = 999
  idx2 = 999
  if [yi_1,yi,i] in all_fea:
    idx1 = all_fea.index([yi_1, yi, i])
  if [yi, i] in all_fea:
    idx2 = all_fea.index([yi, i])

  if (idx1!=999)&(idx2!=999):
    return [[1,weights[idx1]],[1,weights[idx2]]]
  elif (idx1!=999)&(idx2==999):
    return [1,weights[idx1]]
  elif (idx1==999)&(idx2!=999):
    return [1,weights[idx2]]
  else:
    return None
```

featfun(1,1,2) returns [[1, 0.6], [1, 0.8]].

then I combine python_based featfun with for loops again:

```
for k in [2,3]:
  for i in [1,2]:
      return featfun(1,i,k)
```

following is the return results, the correct result, that is the same as the answer in textbook.

```
[[1, 0.6], [1, 0.8]]
[[1, 1], [1, 0.5]]
[1, 0.8]
[[1, 1], [1, 0.5]]
```

what happen with my R codes ? Or it seems that something wrong in R?
I hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you have many times `It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details` in your code. Could you please edit these comments and add more details (when applicable).

Comment: this is a  simple realization of conditional random field model, it comes from a textbook, but in chinese edition. sorry..

Comment: Please edit the question and add some more background on conditional random field, if you would like to motivate someone to answer you. For example, why should you get the expected result? Now it is not clear why expected result is better than the result you got..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not fully sure *why* this issue is coming up, but it'a numerical precision issue. When you use `seq(1,2)` or `seq(2,3)` they are integers,  the `all_fea` list is numeric, and for some reason (this is unusual) the matching isn't working because of that. If you make the `all_fea` list items integers, then it works:

```
all_fea <- list(c(1L, 2L, 2L),
                c(1L, 2L, 3L),
                c(1L, 1L, 2L),
                c(2L, 1L, 3L),
                c(2L, 1L, 2L),
                c(2L, 2L, 3L),
                c(   1L, 1L),
                c(   2L, 1L),
                c(   2L, 2L),
                c(   1L, 2L),
                c(   1L, 3L),
                c(   2L, 3L))
```

The above is a manual way. Alternately you could leave it as-is and add the line `all_fea = lapply(all_fea, as.integer)`. Anyway, after that change your loop works as expected.

Comment: Many thanks for your correct answer !... I am a new R user .

Comment: I'm not a new R user, but this was a really tough one!